# Getting error while converting JSON to CSV

Tags: python, json

I am getting error while converting to csv.

Here's the json data:

```
"[{"
"test_result"
":"
"{\""
1\ "": {
    \
    ""
    meta_data\ "": {
        \
        ""
        grill_type\ "": \ ""
        Propane\ "",
        \""
        is_frozen\ "": \ ""
        false\ "",
        \""
        item_material\ "": \ ""
        Hotdog\ ""
    },
    \""
    sample_item_index\ "": 1,
    \""
    survey_result\ "": {
        \
        ""
        guess_grill_correct\ "": \ ""
        true\ "",
        \""
        thumbs_up_score\ "": \ ""
        0.4\ ""
    }
}, \""
10\ "": {
    \
    ""
    meta_data\ "": {
        \
        ""
        grill_type\ "": \ ""
        Propane\ "",
        \""
        is_frozen\ "": \ ""
        true\ "",
        \""
        item_material\ "": \ ""
        Hotdog\ ""
    },
    \""
    sample_item_index\ "": 10,
    \""
    survey_result\ "": {
        \
        ""
        guess_grill_correct\ "": \ ""
        true\ "",
        \""
        thumbs_up_score\ "": \ ""
        1.0\ ""
    }
},
```

I'm trying this:

```py
df = pd.read_json("SheetC.json", lines=True , encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-7438734445bf> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_json("SheetC.json", lines=True , encoding="utf-8-sig")

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1117         if orient == "columns":
   1118             self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1119                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1120             )
   1121         elif orient == "split":

ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)
```

Comment: Why does your "json data" look like that? It looks like it's been processed into nonsense.

Comment: Why the `r` and `rstudio` tags? You seem to be using Python...

Comment: That is definitely not a valid json data

Comment: I think you've been given some good pointers; this JSON isn't formatted well.  I think the error gives some hints, at least, if I'm following the structure correctly.  As you've posted it, there is an opening `[` (which signals an array), but there is no `]` ending the array.  Additionally, there's a stray `,` after the _second element_ in your array.  This will also give grief.  @schilli has hinted at this with his post.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your json data has a few syntax errors. Start by removing all that escape characters and cleaning the json data. It should in the end look similar to the following. Afterwards, your read_json call may perhaps run properly.

```
[
    {
        "test_result": {
            "1": {
                "meta_data": {
                    "grill_type": "Propane",
                    "is_frozen": "false",
                    "item_material": "Hotdog"
                },
                "sample_item_index": 1,
                "survey_result": {
                    "guess_grill_correct": "true",
                    "thumbs_up_score": "0.4"
                }
            },
            "10": {
                "meta_data": {
                    "grill_type": "Propane",
                    "is_frozen": "true",
                    "item_material": "Hotdog"
                },
                "sample_item_index": 10,
                "survey_result": {
                    "guess_grill_correct": "true",
                    "thumbs_up_score": "1.0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: How to clean clean the file? Do you have certain code which will help?

Comment: How did you get the json in such a format in the first place? If you could add that information to the question there may be a better way to fetch it in a proper format.